Origin of the phrase "Finger Sandwiches"
"Finger sandwiches" is another name for tea sandwiches, those crustless sandwiches served for afternoon tea: (Image: Wikimedia Commons, Payton Walton)

In this ELL post there's a side-disagreement of whether the word "finger sandwich" is  because it is eaten with your fingers ("finger food") or from being finger-shaped, ("chicken fingers"). Which is it?

You're assuming a level of precision that English simply doesn't have, in this context (but it does with finger rolls, which are so named because of appearance, not how they're held). All you'll get is opinions, which won't necessarily reflect what Anglophones at large think. So it's not even worth voting to migrate to English Language Learners

@FumbleFingers This question isn't about the intent of people using the term generally, it's a question specifically about the etymology of the phrase; that's still conceivably answerable.

That's a ridiculous contention.  "finger sandwich" is just a collocation that's been in print for over a century (but with a meaning so obvious it's almost certainly never been "defined" in any dictionary). Even finger rolls, which do appear in some dictionaries, wouldn't merit any kind of "etymology".

We can find e.g. How to Entertain at Home, Priscilla Publishing Co, 1927: "Finger sandwiches are very attractive and are made by removing the crusts from a double sandwich and then cutting it into strips about one inch wide". The OED has entries for "finger food" and "finger sandwich" both with first citation 1893. If the OP is bothered, they could try and track down the OED's first citation of "finger sandwich" in World (New York) 23 July 1893 20/7.

Probably irrelevant.

Today I learned that phrases which aren't found in the dictionary cannot have etymologies. Who knew?

@FumbleFingers Whether many dictionaries list the term or not does not matter that much.  Someone had to go through old materials to figure out the etymologies in the first place and put them in the dictionary.

That's ridiculous! Nobody "has to figure out" why we use terms like "finger food" and "finger sandwiches"!

In fairness,  etymology is the history and evolution of only words. Phrases, idioms and its ilk, we speak about origins. Dictionaries don't normally include the origins of compound words, that would be impossible to list but fixed phrases such as "stone cold" and "under the weather" are so well-known, and understood by native speakers, their histories are easier to trace back. How would we know the origin of "burnt toast" yet it is just as common but it's merely a pairing of two words,  now someone will find the first recorded "burnt toast" dating back to 17th century...

@FumbleFingers Just so I understand, your opinion here is that it's self-evidently "sandwiches you eat with your hands" and that the sense of "sandwiches sliced into fingers" is so absurd as to be not worth considering, correct?

@Mari-LouA That's a fair objection. I think "finger sandwiches" is a bit closer to a fixed phrase than "burnt toast" is? Or like. There's no ambiguity to me in whether "burnt toast" refers to toast that got burned or toast that got sunburned. "Origin" might be a better word though, you're right.

There's no "etymology" for such a collocation, because it will have been coined and re-coined many times over the years. You seem to think Anglophone are all sitting around waiting for someone to tell us what to call twee crustless sandwiches that usually even have the same colour as fish fingers ("healthy" brown bread, whereas traditional-cut triangle sandwiches are probably still more likely to be white bread! :)

@FumbleFingers Lots of things that seem obvious are wrong, which is the purpose of the exercise in the first place.  There is no real rule that two-word phrases can't appear in a dictionary with etymologies either; many do.  In this very OP we see two plausible etymologies on offer ("finger foods" are not finger-shaped, after all).  In general speakers of a language aren't routinely, independently arriving at the same compound terms for the same things.  It's not impossible but it's nowhere near as common as you suggest.

Without going past the paywall, I see the full OED says Where does the noun finger sandwich come from? Earliest known use 1890s. The earliest known use of the noun finger sandwich is in the 1890s. Behind the login / paywall, the "Etymology" simply says Summary: Formed within English, by compounding. OED's earliest evidence for finger sandwich is from 1893, in World (New York). But if Brits had needed to name such things back then (I've no idea), they could have thought of finger for themselves. Now you've made me look, I'll just say it predates fish finger, first cite 1898

Whether it was intentional, unconscious, or coincidental, many foods eating with the fingers are indeed shaped to distantly resemble fingers. 'chicken fingers' is the exemplar of this class. Some 'finger sandwiches' have a long component, some are squarish. If it is a 'folk' explanation that 'finger sandwiches' are called that because they are small, long, and thin like fingers rather than eaten with the fingers then fine. But aren't all sandwiches eaten with the fingers, isn't that the point of a sandwich? Anyway, excellent question!

This might not take you all the way back to when these “delicate” sandwiches came into being and were named, but as far back as 1890, it wasn’t about a finger shape . . .
In the 1890 Mansfield Cook Book, the finger sandwiches are cut into diamond shapes.
In this August 1915 edition of The Ladies’ Home Journal, the finger sandwiches are cut into in squares, rectangles, hearts, and rounds.

Update (it’s not a finger-shaped sandwich) . . .
For a scholarly take on the matter, see finger sandwich in Food: A Dictionary of Literal and Nonliteral Terms by Robert Palmatier (Professor Emeritus of Linguistics, Department of Foreign Languages and Literatures, Western Michigan University):

FINGER SANDWICH
a finger sandwich. A small, crustless sandwich served as an
appetizer. LA: 1870s. Source: SANDWICH. MWCD: 1762. The finger
sandwich, a type of finger food (q.v.), was orig. called a
“reception sandwich” or “tea sandwich” in Britain. In America, the
finger sandwich consists of either (1) a single piece of bread with
the crust removed, cut in a geometric shape, and topped with sandwich
spread (a mixture such as ham salad, egg salad, or tuna salad) or (2)
a miniature sandwich of two pieces of crustless bread, untoasted,
sandwiched around a spread, cream cheese, or watercress. The bread that is used for making finger sandwiches is called sandwich bread
(DAFD: ca. 1930s): pre-cut, thin-sliced, white bread, which, under its
original name, sandwich loaf, was synonymous with “sliced bread” in
the 1930s. Nowadays, the term sandwich bread can also refer to a
“square” (in cross-section) loaf of sliced white or wheat bread that
is perfectly designed for holding square luncheon meat.
Source: Palmatier, Robert. Food: A Dictionary of Literal and
Nonliteral Terms. United Kingdom: Bloomsbury
Publishing, 2000.

See also the entry for finger food, and scroll to the beginning of the Google Books preview to read the preface and the key to the abbreviations.

Ah. but surely this proves the rule. If I have to explicitly state that my fancy "rectangle cake" is going to be cut into a square, that means that a normal rectangle cake is actually a rectangle.

@Richard Not sure about that. Many pancake recipes specify the use of a pan (and flour & eggs, etc.), but I wouldn't take that to mean that normally pancakes are not made using pans (and flour & eggs, etc.).

Accepting this because of the excellent citations, particularly the Palmatier book.

I'm not sure the origin is known. It's not in etymonline.com, and the full OED just says that was formed by compounding the two words, it doesn't say how they came to be used together with this meaning.
Most sandwiches are intended to be eaten with the fingers, so it's not clear why small sandwiches would be given this specific term. But maybe it's because these can be held very daintily between just the thumb and forefinger of one hand, while larger sandwiches often require 3-4 fingers and may be held in two hands.
On the other hand, finger sandwiches are often triangular (a square sandwich is cut diagonally to make tiny sandwiches), so they're not really finger-shaped, either. But it's possible that this is a recent development, and they were usually cut into strips when the name first caught on.

In a sense I suppose anything one holds is held "in the fingers" but the phrase to me suggests holding something away from your hand with just 2 or 3 fingers.

I was thinking of that, but how many fingers do you use to hold a regular-sized sandwich? I think I use the same 2-3 fingers.

It needs to be pretty large, like a sub or big mac, to need the whole hand to hold it.

I added some more discussion of this.

Reminds me of ladyfingers.

When I do a google image search for "finger sandwiches", nearly all the pictures are long thin things like the OP's. But when I change the search term to "buffet sandwiches", they're mostly triangular. I don't think that difference reflects anything from google's AI - I'm sure it just reflects the actual words that most commonly occur in proximity to the two different types of "finger food" pictures (which as a search term didn't return any actual "sandwiches" in at least the first several hundred pictures).

@tchrist I thought you meant lady's fingers.

@FumbleFingers I've never heard the term "buffet sandwiches". When I google it, it just seems to be a collocation of buffet and sandwich, not a set phrase.

I never intended to suggest "buffet sandwiches" was a "set phrase" (I can't believe any dictionary would waste even virtual ink defining it). Obviously it's just a collocation of buffet and sandwich, but at least it distinguishes relatively formal party / business meeting "finger food" from doorstep sandwiches eaten by many as a "packed lunch", or to keep hungry kids quiet.

@Barmar I’d use all my fingers and cradle it between my hands. Or if eating one-handed I still wouldn’t hold it like a wand.

OED

Finger
II.11. A narrow, elongated piece of anything, broadly resembling a finger in shape and often size; (also) each of two or more such pieces into which something has been divided or of which it is composed. Frequently with reference to food. Cf. Compounds C.1b.i. chocolate finger, fish finger, iced finger, sponge finger.
1839 Mons. de Beaureste partook of his coffee and fingers of toast. H. de la Pasture, Real Pearls in False Setting vol. I. iv. 110

This itself seems  to be an extension of earlier, figurative, uses of finger for anything that projects in a way that its length is far greater than its width - i.e. is "finger-like"

II.Something regarded as resembling a finger in shape, function, etc.
II.6. A finger-like projection.
II.6.a.In a living organism, esp. a plant: each of several projections, protuberances, or lobes forming part of a whole or
extending from a centre; spec. (a) †a lobe of the liver (obsolete);
(b) a banana (considered as part of a ‘hand’: cf. hand n. II.12e). Cf.
also lady's finger n. 2.


Certainly this could be a reasonable explanation, and was explicitly noted in the question itself-- but it doesn't address the question of actual etymology. Every eggcorn and folk etymology also has a similarly feasible claim, but we know them to be false.

Surely you’ve heard of “finger food” which is rarely shaped like a finger

@JayMcEh it doesn't address the question of actual etymology. I thought it was clear enough that the etymology is from the figurative use. Or are you looking for the etymology of "finger"?

"I thought it was clear enough that the etymology is from the figurative use." Please re-read the question. There are two clearly distinct potential etymologies proposed, and your answer does nothing to establish either above the other. It seems that you believe that the "from being finger-shaped" explanation is correct, but you need to actually make the argument. Simply telling us what a finger is shaped like, is not helpful; it only explains why that etymology is plausible, not why the other one is wrong.

Are you being obtuse on purpose or you really don't understand the issue?  The question posed is "are they called 'finger sandwiches' because they look like a finger (like chicken fingers), or because one eats them with the fingers (like such 'finger foods' as peanuts)?"  The issue isn't anyone not knowing what a finger looks like.

@Casey: you are getting quite excited about this. "The question posed is "are they called 'finger sandwiches' because they look like a finger (like chicken fingers), or because one eats them with the fingers (like such 'finger foods' as peanuts)?" What part of Finger -- II.11. A narrow, elongated piece of anything, broadly resembling a finger in shape and often size; (also) each of two or more such pieces into which something has been divided or of which it is composed. are you having difficulty with?

I’m not having difficulty with any part of it. Would you like to go back and read what I said again?

@Casey No, not really. I am awaiting your answer.

I’ve already given one. I completely understand the definition and yet it does not answer the question. Are peanuts “narrow, elongated pieces, broadly resembling a finger in shape”?

You have given no answer on this forum. Perhaps you are mistaking me for someone else? If you want to know about peanuts I suggest you ask a question on Biology SE.

OK, I'm going to assume you are just being deliberately obtuse and stop repeating myself.  Hope you've had fun.

Shorter OED definition of finger-food is "food so served that it can be conveniently eaten without cutlery".  See  https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/collection/finger-food  for some examples.  In the UK it is also used for the first food that is offered to babies so that they can feed themselves using their fingers.  A finger buffet is a help-yourself meal that does not require cutlery (very handy, because it saves on the washing up). So I would assume finger sandwiches are meant to be eaten with the fingers.
